# Shortest walk with alternating colors in a directed graph

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics, directed-graphs

Let $G$ be a directed graph such that every edge is colored (red, yellow or green). I want to compute the shortest walk (possibly with repeated vertices) with the restriction that the colors are alternating: red, green, yellow, red, green , ..., etc (the starting color doesn't matter).

So far my idea is to create a new graph $G'$ such that is has a copy of each vertex (for each color). Then, by adequately placing every colored edge in the new graph I should be able to just run DFS/BFS in the new graph and get the answer. However, I don't know exactly how to correctly place the edges in the new graph $G$, or if this idea works.

Comment: DFS does not give the shortest path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=(V, R \cup G \cup Y)$, where $R$, $G$, and $Y$ are the sets of red, green, and yellow edges, respectively.
I assume you want to find the shortest walk **between a pair of given vertices**. Let these vertices be $s$ and $t$.

Create the graph $G'=(V', E')$ where $V' = \{s', t'\} \cup \bigcup\limits_{v \in V} \{v_r, v_g, v_b \}$ and $E'= \{ (u_r, v_g) \mid (u,v) \in G \} \cup \{ (u_g, v_y) \mid (u,v) \in Y \} \cup \{ (u_y, v_r) \mid (u,v) \in R \} \cup \{ (s', u_r) \mid u \in V\} \cup \{(v_r, t'), (v_g, t'), (v_y, t') \mid v \in V\}$.

Let $\ell$ be length of the shortest color-alternating path between $s$ and $t$ in $G$, and let $\ell'$ be the length the length of the shortest path between $s'$ and $t'$ in $G'$. You have than $\ell' = \ell + 2$. Therefore it suffices to find a shortest path from $s'$ to $t'$ in $G'$. This can be done in linear time in the size of $G'$ (and $G$).